# Element type "ListView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, listview, android-listview

I am making a listview in java XML for android . but an error making me so irritate...i have searched earlier error solutions but they didnt work for me..so please help me.

when i picked the ListView and Button from Graphical Layout, then the code is

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="Button" />

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>
```

This code is working properly.. but when i edit a line code in this way in Listview..

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
*android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
>

</ListView>
```

I am getting and error in the line indicated by * saying :

**" Element type "ListView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>" "**

I think the syntax is correct... Not only in ListView id I try to edit Button then also same error comes and at same place. saying:

**" Element type "Button" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>" "**

I have checked earlier posts but they said that the tags were not closed and did not worked for me. Please suggest and help me ..what to do??

full code is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.bimal.blutooth.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="Button" />

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
>

</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try restarting eclipse.  Your code isn't bringing up any errors on my machine.  Sometimes eclipse has bugs with the way it checks your code.  Sometimes it just needs to be restarted.

If you are game for a workaround this is a similar layout that has more code to it, but it avoids the relative layout

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context="com.bimal.blutooth.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".1">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="352dp" >

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".9">
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: may be ... i will try @user3331142

Comment: It is not working for me.. again when i add a line code in <Button tab as:
     **android:layout_below="@+id/lv1"**
i am getting the same error... @user3331142 what can i do???

Comment: That is super bizzare.  Like I said, it works in eclipse for me, and when I run the code on my phone it works totally fine.  I still believe that its an eclipse bug, but if not, I have absolutely no clue.  I added a workaround to my answer.  It avoids the relative layout but it requires more code

Comment: "Sometimes Eclipse just needs to be restarted." -that made me chuckle

Comment: thanks all... but this error is suffering me frequently.. tried all possibilities.. but still have not got the proper solutions... mysterious...:)

Comment: You know, I doubt this is the problem, but I had a run in with the same error message just a bit ago.  It happened when I was using the intellisense to fill in the code, and I forgot to add the end quotation mark to my code.  Check it and see, but otherwise, this is truly mysterious indeed. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a space **after** **"**

```
eg:<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight=".1">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="352dp" ></ListView>
```

Comment: Add some description here. Logic would help much better than just a piece of code.